# Cropped characters - iOS11 - Alert Dialog

Tags: ios, ios11, uialertview, uialertaction

Cropped characters - iOS11 - Alert Dialog. 
How to fix it?

[[image: Example]]

---

```
func settingsButtonPressed() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let closeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Anuluj", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        //do nothing
    }
    alert.addAction(closeAction)
    let restorePurchases = UIAlertAction(title: "Przywróć zakupy", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.restorePurchases()
    }
    alert.addAction(restorePurchases)

    let refreshCatalogs = UIAlertAction(title: "Odśwież", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    alert.addAction(refreshCatalogs)
    let delPubs = UIAlertAction(title: "Usuń publikacje", style: .destructive) { (action) in
        self.deletePublications()
    }
    alert.addAction(delPubs)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code which shows how you set up `UIAlertController`?

Comment: yes, I posted below

Comment: Are you using the default system font. I.e no UIAppearance changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `NSLocalizedString` instead of hardcoded values. [Usage article here](https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881).

Then just define your titles like that:

```
let cancelButtonText = NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "")
```

And set it:

```
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelButtonText, style: .cancel, handler: nil)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still the same

Comment: Have you chosen the right language (non English) for localizable strings file?

Comment: Hm...I don't even know what to suggest. Have you tried English characters instead just to test? Like "g", "p" and so on. Do they get cropped?

Comment: Same. I also lack ideas

Comment: Hm...try to set `UIAlertController(title: "Some string", message: "Some string",` . Maybe it has something to do with empty title of controller...

Comment: It does not change anything